# How to make my table cell auto fit to contents in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am fetching data from Mysql database and populating them in a table. 
However, i cannot seem to make the cell autofit to contents. I have tried width as the property of the table but i cant get it to work
Would really appreciate your help. Thanks
Here's what i have done so far

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th><center>ID</center></th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th><center>Email</center></th>
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>Package</th>
                        <th>Flexibility</th>
                        <th >Date</th>
                        <th>Departuring From</th>
                        <th>Departure Date</th>
                        <th>Destination</th>
                        <th>Arrival Date</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Consolidator</th>

                      </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                      <?php

                        $query = 'SELECT * FROM queries';

                        $result = mysql_query($query);

                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['name'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['email'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['contactnumber'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['packagedetails'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['flexibility'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['datetoday'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['departure'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['dateofdeparture'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['destination'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['dateofarrival'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['price'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['vendor'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td width=250>';
                            echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="readquery.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
                            echo '&nbsp;';
                            echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="updatequery.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                            echo '&nbsp;';
                            echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="deletequery.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                        } 
                        ?>  
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: please post your output html source, not the php code, and create a jsfiddle.net demo along with your related css if you can.

Comment: unfortunately i cant post an image here since it requires atleast 10 points of reputation. This is my first time here on StackOverflow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with my table. To make it work, i increased the width of my container in which my table was inside, and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I never see you echo `</tr>` or `</td>`. It would be helpful to give us an output of the HTML being generated by your while loop.

Comment: I have made changes to the while loop. Kindly have a look at it